# Paginate blog example from "Laravel 5.4 from Scratch series"

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I followed the Laravel 5.4 from Scratch series and am currently trying to implement pagination into the blog example.

It's easy to get pagination for the homepage:

```
Post::latest()->filter(request(['month', 'year']))->simplePaginate(5);
```

Problem: paginate() or simplePaginate() cannot be called like this:

```
public function index(Tag $tag){
$posts = $tag->posts->paginate(5);
return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

So when I visit /posts/tags/{tag}, it tells me method paginate() doesn't exist. How am I supposed to paginate the results in that case, so that I can still hand over the Eloquent model of Post (which I need to display all the details)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Paginate is a method that works on query builder but you are calling it on collection. You $tag->posts()->paginate(5) and it works.

Comment: @train_fox thank you SO much! one step closer to understanding how laravel works. cheers<3